# Vue Material md-datepicker not updating when model changes in keydown handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I am trying to enhance my component that uses an md-datepicker component from Vue Material.  I want to be able to hit the '+' (or '=') to increment the date and the '-' to decrement the date.   I have added a 'keydown' event listener to the imbedded input which handles the incr/decr.  The model is getting changed (verified by bringing up the date picker dlg) but the component doesn't update.  What am I missing?

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-quick-start-xt184?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce the problem. Do you mind adding one or two sentences how you verified the underlying model changes? Are you supposed to click the input line and then enter ```+``` or ```-``` ?

Comment: With focus on the input, as evidenced by the blinking cursor, hit the + key say 3 times.  No visible change to the displayed date.   However, if you then click on the calendar icon that pops up the date picker dialog, you will see that it is set to 3 days ahead of the date shown in the input.